# Add specific tags to specifi products in a shopify

Tags: tags, shopify, liquid

I have a question as i have been searching this and found nowhere the required answer, can you please help me to find a way to add / assign tag to a product through liquid?
I mean i want to give some specific products some specific tags, as there are thousands of products in a store and doing it manually will take days to add the tags, i want something like this

```html
{% if product.price >1 or <75 %}
{% assign tag="less-than-75" %}
{% else %}
{% assign tag="above75" %}
{% endif %}
```

Please ignore the coding error as i am totally new to the shopify liquid
Thanks in advance
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't add tags to products trough liquid in any way.

You can use the REST api and update the products https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#update via your language per choice ( js/php/python etc.. ) but not with liquid.

The liquid language is for outputting information on the front end from the back-end, not for modifying the information in the back-end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really appreciate
can you help me set the code , if possible ?

Comment: or if you can help me to understand so i do it myself ! Can you guide please

Comment: Long story short you have to have access to `https://localhost`. There are online guides how you can achieve this.